# Lista por línea en un txt a una sola lista en python

Tags: python

Necesito juntar un listado de listas que se encuentran cada una en una línea de un txt.
Lo que tengo en el txt aparece tal que así (son precios que almacena el programa tras cada ejecución del script que pretendo pasar después a una gráfica):

```
['785.734']
['785.734']
['785.734']
['785.734']
['785.734']
['785.734']
['785.734']
```

Lo que quiero conseguir para pasarlos a una gráfica es esto

[785.734,785.734,785.734,785.734,785.734,785.734,785.734]

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme,
Gracias de antemano.
"""

Comment: muestra por favor qué has intentado

Comment: ¿Es un punto decimal o un separado de miles en 785.734?

Comment: Es un punto decimal. Gracias fedorqui, ya lo he solucionado con el código de Candid, gracias por tu ayuda de todos modos.

Answer (score 1):

```
texto = """
['785.734']\n
['785.734']\n
['785.734']\n
['785.734']\n
['785.734']\n
['785.734']\n
['785.734']\n
"""

lista = [float(linea[2:-2]) for linea in texto.split()]
print(lista)
```

produce:

```
[785.734, 785.734, 785.734, 785.734, 785.734, 785.734, 785.734]
```

`texto` contiene líneas separadas por "\n". Con `split` convierto `texto` en una lista de lineas.

Cada línea contiene una cadena como esta:

```
['785.734']
```

Para recuperar el valor debo descartar los dos primeros y dos últimos caracteres, lo que hago con *rebanado* de listas. El resultado lo convierto a `float`.

Todo lo anterior se realiza dentro de una compresión de listas, produciendo la lista deseada.

Comment: Al ponerlo así me sale el siguiente error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: salida = []
        with open('hormigon_limpieza_m3.txt', 'r') as f:
            lineas = [linea.split() for linea in f]

        for linea in lineas:
            print(linea)
        x = np.ndim(salida)
        print(x)
        
        
        salida = [float(linea[2:-2]) for linea in salida.split()]
        print(salida)

Comment: @r2d2 Como estás leyendo de un archivo línea a línea, no necesitas hacer el `split`. Sacalo

Comment: Genial, sacando el split ya si sale, solo faltaría una cosa cambiar el linea[2:-2] por 0 y -1 respectivamente y ya funcina perfectamente. Muchas gracias Candid